# Get number of jira users

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

How can I get the number of JIRA users? And how can I get the user number JIRA is licenced for?

I'll appreciate if you provide examples using different layers e.g. Using database query, or JIRA API call, or a method to call in JIRA plugin.
// JIRA instance is using Crowd

Comment: Look here - https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-users-counting-towards-the-jira-application-license-278695452.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to get users from group jira-users. Only this user group affects license user count.

```
ComponentAccessor.getGroupManager().getUserNamesInGroup("jira-users").size();
```

You could also inject groupManager in your plugin.

I don't know how to get user number JIRA is licenced for. I think it's not stored in your instance data or DB.

Comment: Thanks! I used com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserUtil instead and its methods getUsers() and canActivateNumberOfUsers(int) :) Do you know something about licensing your custom JIRA plugin? Please, write me if so (zmiter.mde@gmail.com) Russian language is fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/get-list-of-licensed-users-in-jira-server-278695452.html

But to have the exact licence count, the SQL query must be improved by adding this clause << AND group_id = 'jira-users' >>

So the query is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.lower_user_name
FROM   cwd_user u
       JOIN cwd_membership m
         ON u.id = m.child_id
            AND u.directory_id = m.directory_id
       JOIN licenserolesgroup lrg
         ON Lower(m.parent_name) = Lower(lrg.group_id)
       JOIN cwd_directory d
         ON m.directory_id = d.id
WHERE  d.active = '1'
       AND u.active = '1'
    AND license_role_name = 'jira-software'
    AND group_id = 'jira-users'; // <- improvement
```